# Is there a way to obtain shops location near the gps of the phone

Tags: android

Im developing an app that im struggling to find info for...

The requirements are that the client will be able to determine the shops/resturants near the location of  him currently.

I know other applications provide this however is there a way that I can integrate this into my application and if you guys know of any forums that explain or demonstrate this please inform me

Regards

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/). It allows you to set a radius for the given location to search for a place like restaurants or POIs in general.

Comment: does this attach to my app or is it a separate app that i link to through my app it does not specify this on the link

Comment: This is not a an App but a web-service from Google, which you can access over http.

Comment: ok so i will make an http link through my app whick will link to the web to this site once ive set up and registered etc then i will give me the requirements i desire?

Comment: In short: yes. In long: choose the desired service, like Place Searches or Places Actions, and have a look about the options you have. Then make your call to the site and you will get a JSON with all data available for your request